# How to set conditional visibility of a dynamic dropdown menu in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-material-menu in my list to optionally select "edit" & "delete" action. It works perfectly fine when there's only one on the list. However, when rendering multiple data in list, and click 3 dots menu icon it will showing multiple dropdown too since my condition applied to all data list.

Here's my code:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
const hideMenu = () => setVisible(false);
const showMenu = () => setVisible(true);

<Block style={styles.listContainer}>
                <Text muted style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 5 }} >Unassigned 0 employees | 0 manager, you</Text>
                <Block middle style={{ marginTop: 14, marginBottom: 16 }}>
                    <Block style={styles.divider} />
                </Block>
                <FlatList
                    ref={flatListRef}
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Item item={item} index={index} />}
                    refreshing={isRefreshing}
                    onRefresh={handleRefresh}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    ListFooterComponent={() =>
                        !isAtEndOfScrolling && (
                            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="gray" />
                        )
                    }
                />

                <Button onPress={()=> gotoNewTeam(null, 'create')} color="default" style={styles.button}>
                    Create team
                </Button>
            </Block>




<Block style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Ionicons onPress={showMenu} name="ellipsis-vertical" size={14} color="#8898aa" />
  <Menu
      visible={visible}
      onRequestClose={hideMenu}
   >
      <MenuItem onPress={()=> gotoNewTeam(item, 'update')}>Edit</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onPress={()=> showAlert(item.id)}>Delete</MenuItem>
  </Menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would iterate through the blocks with map and use index properties to toggle the selected menu.

I didn't test but something like that :

````
  const myProps = [
    { employee: 'whatever', managers: 'whatever' },
    { employee: 'whatever', managers: 'whatever' },
    { employee: 'whatever', managers: 'whatever' },
  ];

  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(undefined);

  myProps.map((data, index) => {
    <Block {...data}>
      <Ionicons
        onPress={() =>
          activeIndex !== index
            ? setActiveIndex(index)
            : setActiveIndex(undefined)
        }
        name={'ellipsis-vertical'}
        size={14}
        color={'#8898aa'}
      />
      <Menu visible={activeIndex === index} onRequestClose={() => setActiveIndex(undefined)}>
        <MenuItem onPress={() => gotoNewTeam(item, 'update')}>Edit</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onPress={() => showAlert(item.id)}>Delete</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </Block>;
  });
```
````